# Stripe Javascript library confirmCardPayment not returning

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments

I'm attempting to use Stripe as a payment method, on an ASP.Net MVC project

We've gone the route of using stripe elements to define our own look and feel for the card details.

I've followed the tutorials, and have managed to get the card widgit displaying nicely.

[image]

Where it fails is on the submission.

I've hooked up the following JS to the button (taken straight from the guides)

```
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    var clientSecret = $("#authcode").val();
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault();
      stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
        payment_method: {
          card: card,
          billing_details: {
            name: 'Jenny Rosen'
          }
        }
      }).then(function(result) {
        if (result.error) {
          // Show error to your customer (e.g., insufficient funds)
          console.log(result.error.message);
        } else {
          // The payment has been processed!
          if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
            // Show a success message to your customer
            // There's a risk of the customer closing the window before callback
            // execution. Set up a webhook or plugin to listen for the
            // payment_intent.succeeded event that handles any business critical
            // post-payment actions.
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

Now when I put a breakpoint on it does enter the `stripe.confirmCardPayment` function

However I never get a response. I've put a break point on the line `if (result.error) {` but it never fires. I've sat and left it for over two minutes.

No errors in the chrome console, and also no network traffic.

I am happy that the JS is all loaded correctly because if I hit submit again the Stripe JS lib correctly tells me I have an in-flight confirmCardPayment

Any suggestions are most appreciated.

Comment: What sort of environment is this running it, and cant your reproduce it in a jsfiddle etc? What test card are you using in the `card` element before calling this? There should be network traffic when you call this. Trying in a private/incognito tab might also help to eliminate privacy extensions from interfering.

Comment: Hi, am running the environment through a visual studio .net project so its hosted in the inbuilt debugger, so don't think I can easily port this to a jsfiddle as the client secret is generated with backend c# code. The test card is exactly as shown in the picture from my initial post

Comment: Ah I don't think the image loaded the first time I view this, sorry! OK thanks. Can you try in a private browser tab to see if the behaviour changes?

Comment: Hi @NolanH Just tried Icognito mode and it's working as expected!

Do you think this is some form of caching issue?

Comment: Further update! I've done a full cache clear and it still only works in Incognito mode.

Any further suggestions?

Comment: Do you have any privacy/tracking-related extensions active? This kind of behaviour is most commonly seen with extensions blocking Stripe.js from operating. I'd suggest disabling all extensions to see if it's resolved, then re-enabling one by one. If you can identify one that is causing the issue I'd recommend sharing that with Stripe support so that it can be investigated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks you are using jQuery at:

```
var clientSecret = $("#authcode").val();
```

You should wrap js with

```
$(document).ready(function(){
....
}):
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the speedy response. Yes am using JQuery. I've only put a snippet of a larger segment of code that is already wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function(){` code block.

Also if I change `var clientSecret = $("#authcode").val();` to `var clientSecret = 'bob';` as a test the Stripe API correctly tells me that I have an invalid client secret

Comment: Is #authCode element an input field? val() works only for inputs

Comment: Hi yes its an input field, this part of it is working fine, its just the fact I never get a response from confirmCardPayment unless in incognito mode as identified above from suggestion by nolan

Comment: Looks like cache is to blame. CTRL+SHIFT+DEL and get rid of this

Answer (score 0):

Right, I've finally got it working.

Yes I believe with the answers given by Nolan / Raphael that it was indeed a caching issue!

However. Deleting the cache with CTRL+SHIFT+DEL had no effect.

Only way I could get the cache to clear was to physically alter the JS.

Thanks again to Nolan / Raphael for their suggestions :)